# Default gateway displays different

Tags: windows-phone-8, ip, wifi

On a domain server wireless router is given a IP address - 192.168.1.200. I have configured my laptop giving the router IP (1.200) as the default gateway and internet works fine. Windows phone doesn't allow to set Static IPs and Phone displays default gateway as 192.168.1.1 and DNS suffix displays the company domain. Internet doesn't work. I have configured other OS mobile phones in static works fine. Is there any way i could play with the router settings and get this fixed?

Appreciate your support.

Comment: This question isn't related to programming. It should be asked on the StackExchange website dedicated to Windows Phone usage: http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Check that the wireless router is acting  as a NAT gateway with its own DHCP pool for wireless clients.  The DHCP pool can also use IP addresses 192.161.1.xxx range without conflict because router uses its own IP address on the corp net for all its NAT clients.  Then you should not need any static configuration for either phone or your laptop.